# Android, change position of a button setOnTouchListener

Tags: android

I have been trying to move a button in the screen, I tried a lot of things but none worked properly:

I create button programmatically, and the method must be implanted in the creation time... so i did this:

```
btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public boolean on_Click(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int x = 15;


        }
    });`
```

always enters in the event onclick, but not in the on touch...  What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) it acts differently than an OnClickListener and you can apply it to different views like custom buttons, textviews, etc.